# How to split a 2 columns paper for a big formula

Tags: equations, two-column

A have a 2 column paper, and I have a big formula like:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,article,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

Therefore, triplets of the sensory score for aroma of that sample was calculated as:
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:eq1}
\text{S598A} = \dfrac{\text{0(0 0 25)+ 2(25 25 25)+ 3(50 25 25) + 14(75 25 25) + 6(100 25 0)}}{0+2+3+14+6} 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

and since I do not know how to split the 2 columns, in that exact space.
I tried every tip that I could found, but nothing works.

Thanks all in advance

Comment: why are you using `\text` here?

Answer (score 1):

You can make the equation fit in the column, or you can put it in a two column float.

I avoided `\text` as it uses text spacing and inconsistent spacing around the `+` which I assume was not wanted. I also avoided numeric keys for `\label`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,article,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:triplets-a}
\mathrm{S598A} = \frac{
0(0\ 0\ 25)+ 2(25\ 25\ 25)+
 3(50\ 25\ 25)\\
 + 14(75\ 25\ 25) +
 6(100\ 25\ 0)
}
{0+2+3+14+6} 
\end{equation}
\end{figure*}

blah 
\newpage
blah 
\newpage
Therefore, triplets of the sensory score for aroma of that sample was calculated as:
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:triplets-b}
\mathrm{S598A} = \frac{
\begin{gathered}
0(0\ 0\ 25)+ 2(25\ 25\ 25)+
 3(50\ 25\ 25)\\
 + 14(75\ 25\ 25) +
 6(100\ 25\ 0)
\end{gathered}}
{0+2+3+14+6} 
\end{equation}
Therefore, triplets of the sensory score for aroma of that sample was calculated as shown in \ref{eq:triplets-a}


\newpage
blah blah blah
\end{document}
```